# How does the Ranger's Extra Attack feature work with Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, ranger, two-weapon-fighting, multiattack

I think I know the answer to this one but I'm double checking.

At the 5th level the Ranger gets Extra Attack, which lets them attack a second time during the Attack action. If they are fighting with 2 weapons, the second weapon normally uses their bonus action.

Does this mean when using the Extra Attack and using two weapons, a ranger can attack twice during the Attack action, and still make 1 extra attack as a bonus action, for a total of 3 attacks?

Comment: Related: [Dual Wielding and Extra Attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79589/dual-wielding-and-extra-attacks)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get two attacks with your main weapon, and one with your off hand weapon (if you want them).

Your *attack* action gets you two hits with your main weapon. After you take the attack action, you can then take a special bonus action to make the off hand attack. This is a single attack.

So yes, you get 3 attacks, two with your main weapon, and the third with your off hand weapon.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it requires that your Attack action use only one weapon, which is not the case. The Attack action doesn't give you "two attack *with your main weapon*" it simply gives you "two attacks"