# Dual Wielding and Extra Attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack, two-weapon-fighting, multiattack

From the Rules (EXTRA ATTACK)

"Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn."

If I have the EXTRA ATTACK feature (level 5), AND I am using two different light weapons, I'll get three attacks.

Do the rules ever explicitly stipulate that the two attacks from Extra Attack MUST come from the same weapon in this situation?  I can't find anything saying they must.

Assuming you can make one attack with each weapon, and then a third attack as a bonus action with either weapon (there is no handedness in D&D 5e) the end result would still only be 3 attacks, but might make for a more "fun" 1/2/1 rather than always being the same old 1/1/2 attack sequence.

Assuming using Extra Attack for a 1/2 weapon combo is legal (again- I see nowhere that it's not), does that mean ASIDE FROM 1/1/2:

1/2/2 is the only other legal combination (the bonus attack must be made with the opposite hand of the first attack when the action was taken).

1/2/1 is the only other legal combination (the bonus attack must be made with the opposite hand of the last attack before the bonus action).

OR since both weapons have been used to attack does the player then have the option of which weapon to use?

Comment: Related: [How does the Ranger's Extra Attack feature work with Two-Weapon Fighting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49040/how-does-the-rangers-extra-attack-feature-work-with-two-weapon-fighting)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two-weapon fighting sections says:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.

With that in mind, the only restriction is that one attack must be with each weapon. The extra attack class feature has no restrictions on the weapon used. This has been confirmed by the [Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/upload/articles/SA_Compendium.pdf) column by WotC:

> ***When you use Extra Attack, do you have to use the same weapon for all the attacks***? Extra Attack imposes
>   no limitation on what you use for the attacks. You can use regular weapons, improvised weapons, unarmed strikes, or a combination of these options for the attacks.

Therefore, you are correct. 1/1/2, 1/2/2, 1/2/1, 2/2/1, etc are all valid options.

**Note** also that the two-weapon fighting style allows you to add your ability modifier to the bonus action attack, not the "off-hand" weapon since, as you pointed out, handedness isn't a thing in 5e.

Comment: Link 404s. Here's an updated link: https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf