# Can I use the same weapon for a normal attack and Two-Weapon Fighting in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack, two-weapon-fighting

Two-weapon fighting rules, per the Player's Handbook (page 195):

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

Per [my earlier question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129803/can-you-attack-with-different-weapons-using-extra-attack), I am allowed to use different weapons for an Attack action if I have the Extra Attack class feature. Let's assume I did just that, attacking once each with a hand-axe and once with a shortsword. Am I allowed to afterwards perform a Two Weapon Fighting bonus attack with one of these weapons?

Comment: Weird, I seem to recall there being references to a "main" weapon, but that's not in the rules, maybe that's what confused me.

Comment: You might be remembering previous editions, where there was often an important distinction between main-hand and off-hand in two-weapon fighting rules.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes

The bonus action has three criteria for triggering:

- You take the Attack action
- You make an attack with a light one-handed melee weapon
- You are wielding or can draw a light one-handed melee weapon with the
  other hand

If you have multiple attacks in a single Attack action because of Extra Attack, **you only need to consider one of the individual attacks you make when triggering the two-weapon-fighting bonus action**, not the entire Attack action and all attacks you made as part of it.

So if you are fighting with a shortsword and a handaxe, and you make one attack with each as part of your Attack action:

- You took the Attack action and made an attack with your shortsword, so you can use a two-weapon-fighting bonus action to make an attack with the handaxe
- You took the Attack action and made an attack with your handaxe, so you can use a two-weapon-fighting bonus action to make an attack with the shortsword

Of course, you still only get one bonus action per turn - so TWF only ever gets you one bonus attack, even if you have a choice of multiple weapons you could use it with.

Comment: @vonBloomslang There's a third criteria missing, although it's pretty expected.  You are required to use a different weapon in the opposite hand of one of the standard attacks you made.  As it reads right now, from Carcer's answer, someone with a light weapon and a shield can make the bonus action attack.