# Can you attack four times when you have two light weapons and the extra attack skill?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting

Most, if not all, classes gain the extra attack ability at level 5 where you can attack twice on your go instead of once. But if you are weilding two light weapons when you're using extra attack, do you get an extra attack with each weapon, leaving you with four attacks in total? Or do you attack twice with one weapon and only do one other attack with the other weapon, leavin you with three attacks? Or is it none of the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can make three attacks.

The relevant wording of the two-weapon-fighting rules is:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

And Extra Attack:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Extra Attack only applies when you take the Attack action, specifically. The bonus action attack you are granted by two-weapon-fighting is an attack, but it is not the Attack action, so Extra Attack does not apply to it, and it can only ever be one singular attack. Altogether, you can make two attacks with your action and one attack with a bonus action.

Bonus note: the Attack action doesn't specify you must only use one weapon for all your attacks if you happen to be wielding multiple ones; you could make one attack with each hand and then make your bonus action attack with either of your wielded weapons (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129905/28402)).

Answer (score 3):

## You get three attacks with Extra Attack and two weapon fighting

When you engage in two weapon fighting, you make the second attack with your bonus action. You only have one bonus action per turn, so you can only do this once.

> **[Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting)**
> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

And from [Bonus Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions):

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

When you gain Extra Attack at 5th level, it allows you to use your action to make two attacks, but you still only have the one bonus action so you can still only make a total of three attacks.

From a Fighter's [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ExtraAttack-196) (all use similar wording):

> **Extra Attack**
> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.