# Can I use the Two Weapon Fighting bonus action attack while only holding one weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting

Here's the situation.
A level one Tabaxi fighter has claws and a mace.  He intends to attack with both weapons. Using claws as his off hand attack.  He is fighting a monster that has resistance to slashing.
His friend attacks with a slashing weapon and he sees that it barely damaged the monster.
On his initiative he attacks and does standard damage with the mace.
Realizing this, he uses his free action to "draw" the mace from his primary hand to attack with it as a bonus action using his off hand.

Is this legal RAW?

Comment: Related, but distinct: [Can I use the same weapon for a normal attack and Two-Weapon Fighting in the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129905/52137)

Comment: As written, the answer is immediately obvious from the rules for TWF, so I am voting to close for "needs details", in particular, is there something about the TWF rules that is unclear or confusing? I'd hope that there is something else going on here and we can be more helpful to you than to just quote a rule you seem to already be aware of.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the best way to ask an "when X, I say the rules say Y, am I understanding this correctly?" question is to leave it to "when X, what happens?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The rule (PHB, page 195) for fighting  with two weapons says:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light
> melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can
> use a bonus action to atlack with a **different light melee
> weapon** that you're holding in the other hand.

None of the upgrades for two weapon fighting remove the part where it says "different weapon", so you need to actually attack with two different weapons.

Also, keep in mind that by default you have to use two **light** melee weapons to qualify for two-weapon fighting, and the Mace is not light. So your Tabaxi probably can't use two-weapon fighting with it at all.

Comment: You might also want to mention that maces aren't light and so don't qualify for two weapon fighting. Could use clubs though

Comment: I suspect this is a "read the book to me" question as described in [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions). I've deleted my answer per the guidance there. I'd recommend deleting this answer temporarily and voting to close until we get more details from OP about what the problem is here.